# Oracle not resetting/reinitialising a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following example PL/SQL code:

```
create table messages
(
  when timestamp,
  what varchar2(200)
)

create or replace package init_test

is
  procedure set(
    w varchar2
  );
  procedure report(
    msg varchar2
  );
end;

create or replace package body init_test
is
  wibble varchar2(100);

  procedure set(
    w varchar2
  ) is
  begin
    wibble := w;
    report('Setting ' || w);
  end; 

  procedure report(
    msg varchar2
  ) is
    pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  begin
    insert into messages values(current_timestamp, 'Wibble := ' || wibble);
    insert into messages values(current_timestamp, msg);
    commit;
  end;  
begin 
  report('Init called');
end; -- End of package body

begin
  init_test.set('Init test');
  init_test.report('Hello world');
  dbms_session.reset_package;
  init_test.report('Goodbye world');
end;
/
```

After running it, `messages` contains:

```
23-FEB-18 08.23.24.439726000    Wibble := 
23-FEB-18 08.23.24.440028000    Init called
23-FEB-18 08.23.24.440267000    Wibble := Init test
23-FEB-18 08.23.24.440435000    Setting Init test
23-FEB-18 08.23.24.440597000    Wibble := Init test
23-FEB-18 08.23.24.440747000    Hello world
23-FEB-18 08.23.24.440947000    Wibble := Init test
23-FEB-18 08.23.24.441098000    Goodbye world
```

Why is "init called" not featuring twice in the table? Is there an alternative so that the package is reset and re-initialised?

**EDIT**

From @XING answer - I have tried the following - but it still has the same problem.

```
create table messages
(
  when timestamp,
  what varchar2(200)
)


create or replace package P is
  cnt    number := 0;
  cursor c is select * from all_objects;
  procedure print_status;
  procedure report(
    msg varchar2
  );
end P;
/

create or replace package body P is
  procedure report(
    msg varchar2
  ) is
    pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  begin
    insert into messages values(current_timestamp, msg);
    commit;
  end; 

  procedure print_status is
  begin
    report('P.cnt = ' || cnt);
    if c%ISOPEN then
      report('P.c is OPEN');
    else
      report('P.c is CLOSED');
    end if;
  end;
end P;
/

begin
   P.cnt := 111;
   open p.c;
   P.print_status;
   dbms_session.modify_package_state(dbms_session.reinitialize);
   P.print_status;
end;
```

Comment: Where is the end of your package body ? I cannot find it in your code. Can you put it ? Also i couldnot understand why you expect "init called" twice when you executed it once.

Comment: After the reset - should the package reinitialise?

Comment: Yes after `dbms_session.reset_package` all packages in this session will be de-instantiated. when you say de-instantiated means it only frees the memory, cursors, and package variables after the PL/SQL call that made the invocation finishes running. To reinitialise variable you might need to use `DBMS_SESSION.REINITIALIZE `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the reset - should the package reinitialise?

As far i could understand your question you might need `dbms_session.reinitialize` in place of `dbms_session.reset_package` if you are looking to reintialize your pacakge. `Reinitialization` is different than `RESETING`. Reinitialization refers to the process of resetting all package variables to their initial values and running the initialization block (if any) in the package bodies where as `RESET_PACKAGE` only frees the memory, cursors, and package variables after the PL/SQL call that made the invocation finishes running.

See below example of reinitialization.

```
create or replace package P is
  cnt    number := 0;
  cursor c is select * from emp;
  procedure print_status;
end P;
/

create or replace package body P is
  procedure print_status is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('P.cnt = ' || cnt);
    if c%ISOPEN then
      dbms_output.put_line('P.c is OPEN');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('P.c is CLOSED');
    end if;
  end;
end P;
/

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2   P.cnt := 111;
  3   open p.c;
  4   P.print_status;
  5  end;
  6  /
P.cnt = 111
P.c is OPEN

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin
  2   dbms_session.modify_package_state(dbms_session.reinitialize);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2   P.print_status;
  3  end;
  4  /
P.cnt = 0
P.c is CLOSED

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```